# Creating a flexible DIV that filters elements using HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following this tutorial from W3: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

The implementation on W3 is static and leaves white space on the right side of the elements when they overflow:

[image: Div implementation with excess whitespace]

I was wondering how their code could be adjusted so that there is no excess white space on the right side, and so that the elements are flexible. The HTML/CSS/JS code is on the original website. Any help would be appreciated, I am a beginner when it comes to this kind of stuff.

Edit: This implementation of the CSS aspect of this problem was provided, and it only works for "Show All." When Other categories are selected, the elements that don't apply disappear while still occupying space. I believe the fix involves the JavaScript aspect of this div.
[image]

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a light grey background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Add a dark background to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Control buttons -->
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<!-- The filterable elements. Note that some have multiple class names (this can be used if they belong to multiple categories) -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this? https://i.ibb.co/427ZMxq/Picture4.png
In there I have removed both left and right space.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve or mean by "excess white space on the right side". There are 13 divs, 13 is prime so no number of rows could exist (except 1) without free space, inless the divs has different widths. Could you be clearer in what you mean?

Comment: I was wondering how to make the elements in the div scalable by width so that they conform to the screen size without any left over space, basically making the margins of the left and right side identical for all screen sizes. I was thinking about using flexgrid but the javascript implementation conflicts with this.

Comment: Vishal, would that work for all screen sizes? So if I make the tab smaller, the left and right margins will stay the same?

Comment: It will be working like this when you change the screen size. https://i.ibb.co/RNsQ8Zr/Picture5.png I think nothing was happened to the left and right margin as the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In my HTML, "filterDiv" was only used for a div containing the img src. This did not include the exterior 'div' and 'a' it was wrapped in, so those elements took up space. I fixed the HTML of each element by making it the following.

```
<div class="filterDiv classic 2010 hiphop">
                <a href="https://soundcloud.com/tfrye/sets/friday-night-lights"  id="fnl-jcole" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51LMdp1N8bL._SL1000_.jpg" title="Friday Night Lights • J. Cole" class="fit-box" alt="Friday Night Lights by J. Cole Album Cover">
                </a>
            </div>
```

As you can see, filterDiv is now used for the exterior div.